# UITextView content not appearing in UIAlerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, uialertview

The content is about 230 lines.  It does not appear in UITextView except when you click on it AND try to scroll down.  Otherwise, it is a white blank view.

Any ideas why?

```
    UITextView *termsOfService = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 100.0, 245.0, 170.0)];
    termsOfService.text = responseString;
    termsOfService.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    termsOfService.editable = NO;
    termsOfService.delegate = self;
    [alert addSubview:termsOfService];
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because UIAlertView isn't intended to have subviews added to it. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I would add that is is bad interface design to put a textview inside an alert. That is not what they are for.

Comment: TechZen is right. It'll violate the HIG and Apple probably won't like it during review. I've seen apps that use text fields in the alert view for username/password capture, like the App Store app does, and Apple used to reject them from the store, but recently they seem to be allowing it... I still don't think they'd go for a 230 line text view in the alert though.